# Exact same mesh and UV's, one scaled minus one, and UV's started to strecth

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm a beginner 3D modeller, and I have been having issues with my recent work. I'm not exactly sure if the issue caused after I scaled it. I've been working on this project for quite some time and noticed the problem after texturing. I was making stairs for a tower, since stairs are mostly repetitive I was continuously duplicating, flipping etc.

So the ones I scaled -1 in X axis appear stretched like this. Their tangents and binormals appear different in unreal engine too.

[image: Text]

And Blender's angle based  stretching overlay looks like this. (Normally they are overlapping. One in the left is working correctly, right one is  stretching.)

[image: Text]

Edit: I just checked if they are identical with overlapping both and adding boolean modifier. Although they look quite similar they aren't %100 identical. Probably at some point I messed up. Although I would still love to know how I could solve an issue like this without just going back and start replicating again.